# Finite Element boundary normal vector

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, numerical-methods, parametric, finite-element-method

I have a finite element and the meshs coordinates can be described using isoparametric shape functions as:

$x(\xi, \eta) = \sum _i N_i(\xi, \eta)x_i$, $y(\xi, \eta) = \sum_i N_i(\xi, \eta)y_i$

I need to evaluate the outward boundary normal vectors (not the surface normal, but the edges normals, i.e., the vector is contained in the elements plane) of a given element using the isoparametric shape functions $N_i(\xi, \eta)$.

Any idea how can I perform this for any given shape function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\eta = 0$ for instance.
A tangent vector is
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi}(\xi, 0) 
\\ 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial \xi}(\xi, 0)
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
By rotation of -90 degrees, an outward normal vector is
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} 
- \frac{\partial y}{\partial \xi}(\xi, 0)
\\ 
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi}(\xi, 0)
\end{matrix} \right]
$$
You can proceed similarly for the other edges.